# Keeping track of contracts, subscriptions and the likes

Tags: contract-manager

We are an architecture office of 12 people.

I've been tasked with finding a tool that lets us keep track of contracts, software subscriptions, and other contracts such as lease, cleaning. We have contracts where we are the customer and others where we are the client. The software should have place to add information and send us notifications by email when contracts/subscriptions are about to expire or be renewed.

We don't need to be able to send contracts to clients from this software, it's only for internal use.

Thank you!